# Delete files required by OS X

Tags: trash, library

Carbon copy cloner made a few copies of my hard drive when it was cloning some stuff for me, and put them in a SafetyNet folder.

It copied my library directory with some stuff in it, I was able to get a lot of the stuff erased with "Empty Trash."

Other items like these, I can't change permissions on them, I can't get them erased, even with third party tools. I can't get them erased with `sudo rm` commands.

```
/Users/Henry/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet/2015-08-05 (August 05) 12-47-55/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeDirectory
/Users/Henry/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet/2015-08-05 (August 05) 12-47-55/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeRequirements
/Users/Henry/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet/2015-08-05 (August 05) 12-47-55/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
/Users/Henry/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet/2015-08-05 (August 05) 12-47-55/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeSignature
```

Any ideas?

---

And besides the files being protected, every directory on the way down is protected too. I have about twenty of these.

Comment: While you said you've used `sudo rm`, have you used: `sudo rm -fr /Users/Henry/.Trash/*`

Comment: Yes @user3439894 `operation not permitted`

Comment: What's the output of: `sudo ls -ale@ "$HOME/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet"`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  5 Henry  wheel   170 Mar 17 19:36 .
drwx------  4 Henry  staff   136 Mar 17 19:38 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Henry  wheel  8196 Mar 17 19:36 .DS_Store
 com.apple.FinderInfo   32 
drwxr-xr-x  4 Henry  wheel   136 Mar 17 19:36 2015-08-05 (August 05) 12-47-55
drwxr-xr-x  4 Henry  wheel   136 Mar 17 17:54 2015-08-10 (August 10) 11-14-12
`

Comment: @user3439894 there it is

Comment: Try: `sudo rm -fr "$HOME/.Trash/_CCC SafetyNet"`

Comment: @user3439894 `operation not permitted`

Comment: @klanomath awesome. Please add an answer

Comment: @henryaaron answer written ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming El Capitan is installed the files are probably still protected by System Integrity Protection due to their origin (/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle...) though they are residing in your user's trash.

So boot to the Recovery HD partition, disable SIP and remove the items:

1. In the menubar open Utilities->Terminal
2. Enter `csrutil disable`
3. Remove the files and folders:

   ```
   rm -fr /Volumes/name_of_main_volume/Users/Henry/.Trash/*
   ```
4. Enable SIP again `csrutil enable`
5. Reboot to your main volume.

Comment: csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.